# Properties of sequences

Tags: calculus, analysis

Are the following properties false or right?

- $ (a_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a bounded sequnce, it applies that

$\ \ -lim \ \sup_{n \rightarrow \infty}(-a_{n})= lim\ \sup_{n \rightarrow \infty}(a_{n})$

- $ (a_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\ \ (b_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are not negative bounded real sequences, it applies that

$\ \ lim \ \sup_{n \rightarrow \infty}(a_{n}b_{n}) \ge (lim\ \sup_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_{n}) (lim\ \sup_{n \rightarrow \infty}b_{n})$

- $ (a_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a complex sequence where $a \in \mathbb{C}$,
  $(a_{2k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}},(a_{2k+1})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ subsequences  and $(a_{2k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}},(a_{2k+1})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ converge to $a$

$ \implies$ that $(a_{n})$ converges to $a$

My ideas to the properties above:

1. I suppose that it's correct but I still don't know why
2. I guess that after the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem this property is correct, because the sequences are bounded non-negative so it can be also $0$ but in this case the inequality is still correct.so it's right.
3. Well if there are 2 subsequences but it says nothing about the boundedness of the sequence so the convergence of $(a_{n}) is not guaranteed and the statement above is false.

Comment: There is no question in this Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is false.  The correct version is
$$  - \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} (-a_n) = \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n  \text{.}  $$
"$-a_n$" flips the set of points "upside down" so the upper bounds for $a_n$ transform into lower bounds for $-a_n$.  Specifically, let $M$ be an upper bound for $(a_n)_n$.  Then $-M$ is a lower bound for $(-a_n)_n$.

The second one is false.  For $a_n b_n$ to be "large", both $a_n$ and $b_n$ need to be large at the same time.  So if we arrange for this to not happen, for $a_n$ to be small when $b_n$ is large and vice versa...  Let $a_n = 0$ if $n$ is odd and $a_n = 1$ if $n$ is even.  Let $b_n = 1-a_n$.  Notice that the maximum of the $a_n$ and of the $b_n$ is $1$, but $a_n b_n = 0$ for all $n$.  (Zero and one aren't essential.  We could have chosen $2$ and $1/2$.  Then $a_n b_n = 1$ for all $n$ but the two maxima are both $2$.)

The third one is true.  We have two sequences getting closer and closer to $a$.  We need to find a tail of each sequence that is closer than a prescribed bound, for any positive prescribed bound.   Let $\varepsilon > 0$.  Since $(a_{2k})_k$ converges to $a$, there is an $N_1$ such that $|a - a_{2k}| < \varepsilon$ for all $k > N_1$.  Since $(a_{2k+1})_k$ converges to $a$, there is an $N_2$ such that $|a - a_{2k+1}| < \varepsilon$ for all $k > N_2$.  Consequently, for $k > \max\{N_1, N_2\}$, both $|a - a_{2k}| < \varepsilon$ and $|a - a_{2k+1}| < \varepsilon$.  So if $n > 2\max\{N_1, N_2\}$ and $n > 2\max\{N_1, N_2\} + 1$,  $|a - a_n| < \varepsilon$.  But these two conditions on $n$ simplify to $n > 2\max\{N_1, N_2\}+1$.  Therefore, $(a_n)_n$ converges to $a$.